# storing a function as data

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, model

The context for this question comes from an idea I got from [A Universal Person and Organization Data Model](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/).

The author contends that while people can and often do have various components to their name (middle initial, first name, etc), it is pointless and frustrating to anticipate how to store them all, unless you have a clear search requirement to do so. Instead, he says to make one attribute mandatory, the Surname, and store everything else in the "RestOfName".

Whether you like the idea or not, the question I have here is about the PK NameFunction in the model below (the image quality is poor, I know). I am guessing, since it isn't discussed, that it is a way to format and parse the RestOfName.

Have you ever stored a function, literally? I can see how it makes sense in the object model, but I can't picture it a data.

How would you store a function as data?

Cheers,
Berryl

p.s. extra credit if you can figure out what that last attribute is. I would say Salutation although that seems to be contrary to the author's point

[image]

Comment: Salutation! I repeat to achieve minimum characters - Salutation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some languages can evaluate code at runtime; therefore, you could store the code to pass to an eval function.

This dynamic implementation could be quite risky exposing security, integrity, and functional danger.

Comment: Perhaps one could counter - if there was no search or implementation specific reason to separate parts of the name, why not just store it as a singular string value?

Comment: i *guess* allowing for implementation/presentation details that change over time, but only worth it if there is a search. definitely open to debate! but not the question here, fortunately :--)

Comment: You could think about a "toString()" implementation stored as a function in the database.  It's an interesting abstraction - very decoupled from the compiler, its presentation in the data layer based upon that data model.  If you could assure strict standards of that code, it could be very cool.

Comment: And store the function name as a string? That might be as subject to change as a name tho, if not more! Or you work out a format string like numbers have (ie, #0.00) where maybe 'f' is for firstName and 'l' is lastName, but that could be some work too. Can you scratch out some code for what you are thnking??

Comment: [Anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).  JavaScript could load the data (JSON would be cool), and the value of a property would be: function():void { return(data.firstname + ' ' + data.lastname);  You'd just call the property value as a function.  Each object could define this property uniquely.  Otherwise, basically just: eval(dataPayload);

Comment: cool. I don't suppose you know how to do this with c#, if its even possible - but do you?

Comment: oops - that anonymous function should return a string instead of void.

Comment: C# has lambda expressions, but I don't think they can be interpreted dynamically at runtime.  I think c# could also link IronPython, and use Python to perform the eval.  Sorry, not sure about this one - it would be a good follow question to post.

Comment: The OP's linked article doesn't have anything to do with storing code in a database and evaluating it at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood [the article](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/). It does, in fact, tell you *exactly* what NameFunction means.

> Each Party Name has a specific function, such as a legal name or
>   professional name or other alias . . .

Also, not every person has a surname. See, for example, [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Good spot! My brain was so preoccupied with "TheRestOfTheName" I missed that altogether - have *would* you deal with that bit tho??

Comment: Yeah, I took the Surname as poetic license. The author does use it for a company name too, after all. I am calling it "TheRequiredName" in a model I am trying out. Will read your link of "false hoods" soon. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl: How would you deal with which bit?